# How can i compile C++ files through Visual Studio Code

Tags: compiling, c++, ide, visual-studio-code

***Quick run-down***: I'm completely new to Ubuntu, but not new to C++: I've coded on a Windows machine before, but I switched to Ubuntu

Now I've installed VS code on Ubuntu as well as the C++ extension but when I even attempt to run a `helloworld.cpp` and debug my editor starts throwing up gang signs:

[image: Error Screen]

*Can anybody help me with this problem?*

Comment: @dsstorefile1 i added an imgur screenshot of what my editor gives me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too when I switched to Ubuntu (I'm kind of new too, so I will try to be very clear I understand it's more complicated than Windows). I don't know your experience but, first of all, it is not like any Windows compiler (like devc, borland, etc) where it will output your values on a external console (unless you are debugging). So this are the steps to get a program to work:

1. You need to install g++ `sudo apt-get install g++` and show the compiler where is the include route in a file named `c_cpp_properties.json` in the linux section, like this:

   ```
   "name": "Linux",
       "includePath": [
           "/usr/include/c++/7",
           "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7",
           "/usr/include/c++/7/backward",
           "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include",
           "/usr/local/include",
           "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed",
           "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
           "/usr/include",
           "/usr/bin/g++",
           "${workspaceRoot}"
   ```
2. First select the folder you are going to work (it's going to be your workspace).
3. You need to build your program before you put it to work, so you need to create a "task" to do that, so you go to the command pallet (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and type:

   ```
   Tasks: Configure Default Build Tasks
   ```

   That is going to create a `task.json` and you will have to pick an option (MsBuild, dotNet, Other, etc). So you are going to select "Other" and you will change some values like this:

   ```
   {
       // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
       // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
       "version": "2.0.0",
       "tasks": [
           {
               "label": "echo",
               "type": "shell",
               "command": "g++",
               "args": [
                   "-g","Erlang_B_Correcto.cpp"
               ],
               "group": {
                   "kind": "build",
                   "isDefault": true
               }
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
4. Now, if your program has no errors, is going to output something like this in the integrated terminal

   > Executing task in folder YourFolder: g++ -g YourProgram.cpp

   and is going to create a file named `a.out` in your workspace folder, I recommend you download an extension named `CodeRunner`: it adds a play button on the right top corner that you only click and runs the program without debugging.
   The thing is, it can only output. I mean: if you are expecting the user to input values, you can't (As I said before, I'm also new so I'm not entirely sure you can't).
5. Finally, if you want to debug, you need to configure that one `lauch.json` you uploaded in the images to something like this:

   ```
   {
   // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
   // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
   // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [

       {
           "name": "(gdb) Launch",
           "type": "cppdbg",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "/home/carlosrpz26/Documents/C++ Programas/a.out",
           "args": [],
           "stopAtEntry": false,
           "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
           "environment": [],
           "externalConsole": true,
           "MIMode": "gdb",
           "setupCommands": [
               {
                   "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                   "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                   "ignoreFailures": true
               }
           ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofrpi.jpg

**Pro tip:** *I would recommend a darker theme!*

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the effort in this response. I'm having trouble though with one of the steps, I'm getting a fatal error in my terminal when i press ctrl+shift+b, I'll post a screengrab of my terminal. And ah a darker theme would be look good but it's very taxing on my eyes! https://imgur.com/a/vsCHusT


edit: i just had to change the name of the .cpp file lol, i've got it running now!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! 
it can be rough sometimes, I wanted to give VSCode a try, I personally didn't like it, I'm looking for a windows like compiler where I just type the code and put it to work, instead of changing the name of the file I want to build (like VSCode). Anyways I had this thing that the program wouldn't beat me so I put some effort to get it done haha.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to build your application from VS Code, you will need to
>   generate a tasks.json file:

**tasks.json is used to execute anything else you may want, be that source code formatters, bundlers or a SASS compiler. To use a configuration from tasks.json, you select Run Task from the command list.**

**Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).**

1. Select the Tasks: Configure Tasks... command, click Create tasks.json file from templates, and you will see a list of task runner templates.
2. Select Others to create a task which runs an external command.
3. Change the command to the command line expression you use to build your application (for example g++).
4. Add any required args (for example -g to build for debugging).
5. **Microsoft C/Cpp extension** is needed, and also your own c++ compiler is required to run the actual code. I have used g++ and it gives .out file after compilation so I have added .out in following snippet.

   ```
   {
       "version": "2.0.0",
       "tasks": [
           {
               "label": "debug",
               "type": "shell",
               "command": "",
               "args": [
                   "g++",
                   "-g",
                   "${relativeFile}",
                   "-o",
                   "a.out"
               ],
               "problemMatcher": [
                   "$gcc"
               ]
           },
           {
               "label": "Compile and run",
               "type": "shell",
               "command": "",
               "args": [
                   "g++",
                   "-g",
                   "${relativeFile}",
                   "-o",
                   "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out",
                   "&&",
                   "clear",
                   "&&",
                   "./${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out"
               ],
               "group": {
                   "kind": "build",
                   "isDefault": true
               },
               "problemMatcher": {
                   "owner": "cpp",
                   "fileLocation": [
                       "relative",
                       "${workspaceRoot}"
                   ],
                   "pattern": {
                       "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                       "file": 1,
                       "line": 2,
                       "column": 3,
                       "severity": 4,
                       "message": 5
                   }
               }
           }
       ]
   }
   ```